# Error With Array In Public Function

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm new to OOP PHP and attempting to build a login function that checks if a user exists in the Database before running the part of the code. To do this, I've used the following to grab the code from the DB and turn it into an array:

```
$Login_Data = $this->select('players', ['Leader', 'Password'], ['Leader' => $Username])->results();
echo $Login_Data['Password'];
```

The first line grabs the Data from the Database, that works fine.

At the next line, I just get undefined index errors. Attempting to use print_r reveals that the array exists, however, any attempt to grab anything from it in that manner gives errors.

Any help here? As I'm probably missing some vital info on how OOP works with arrays and classes.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($Login_Data);`

Comment: Got:

array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Leader"]=> string(4) "USERNAME" ["Password"]=> string(128) "HASH" } } 

Replaced the actual name with USERNAME and Password with HASH for security reasons.

Comment: then its clearly `$Login_Data[0]['Password']`